# Retrieve sorted collection using JPA annotation without using hardcoded strings

Tags: java, sorting, jpa, collections, annotations

In my example, the persisted object contains a collection of items.
I now want to retrieve this collection from the database, such that the items are sorted based on a property (which is an enum, but which is NOT the ID of "Item").

```
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Item> items;
```

I can use `@OrderBy` as follows:

```
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy("propertyOfItem")
    private List<Item> items;
```

However, I really dislike having hardcoded strings in my program. I managed to solve my other problems by using (autogenerated) meta models to reference the fields. Now I'd like to have a similar solution that also makes the database sort according to my specification.

How can I get the behaviour of the code shown above without having to hardcode the string "propertyOfItem"?

EDIT to clarify my intentions (although you may answer this question without understanding these): I want clean code in the sense that renaming a field either makes my code not compile, or (by implementing corresponding cleverness in Eclipse) update the `@OrderBy` equivalent accordingly. I do NOT want my code to compile and run and silently fail when I try to sort based on a field/column that does not exist anymore. I solved a similar problem by using auto-generated meta models (i.e., I can build queries which automatically are updated whenever I rename a field referenced in them). Now I want a similar, clean solution for the problem described here.

Comment: It looks like you'd need the Criteria API, and IMO just dealing with the hardcoded string is a lot less ugly.

Comment: The criteria API only helps if I explicitly build a query. However, the code that works on the (sorted?) list does not know about JPA at all - it just calls container.getItems().

Comment: What do you mean by hard-coding? Defining manually the string "propertyOfItem" in a special file as being `public final static` is still hard-coding? We all are pedantic, but I don't see the reason for being THAT pedantic...

Comment: I hadn't realized `OrderBy` was already present in JPA 1. FWIW, I've tried to solve some similar problems, and it always came down to dealing with reflection at compile time, usually by using annotation processors, and Maven has a longstanding paper-bag bug with annotation processing, so I've gone with hard-coding. A Maven mojo or equivalent might be the only practical option.

Comment: @AndreiI I think he's wanting to avoid having a string literal that's just the name of a field instead of being able to specify that field in a type-safe manner.

Comment: With hard coding I (intend to) mean: not safe from refactoring. In other words, if I decide to rename the field, my code still works. This is the case if my meta models are generated automatically. This is not the case if I use the code as shown in my question.

Comment: @chrylis I still don't get it. Annotations are another way of configuring things, e.g instead of using XML files (which are not type-safe)...

Comment: Yes, but the huge difference is that annotations are part of Java and are also, somehow, checked by the compiler. I'd love to have a Java connection from the value I provide to the @OrderBy annotation (i.e., NOT a string) to the name of the field. If this does not match, I want the compiler to not compile. What I really want is Eclipse to rename accordingly whenever I rename the field. XML files on the other hand just contain text that may or may not be useful.

Comment: OK, I see now the problem. But honestly I wouldn't dedicate a second to that problem (as it happens once a year) and the one who renames an entity property should take that into account (without mentioning that I expect from any JPA provider to complain about inexistent an property)

Comment: I take that advise for upcoming real-life problems. However, I still love to see an answer to this (academic?) question.